# How to use DevTools Network with Selenium 4 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, selenium4

I am using Selenium 4 with Ruby and I'm trying to capture the Network activity, but I can't figure out how to use the libraries and haven't found anything related to this for Ruby.

So what I did is:

- I added the DevTool gem in the Gemfile: `gem 'selenium-devtools', '~> 0.91.1'`
- I the code I'm trying this:

```
devtools = browser.devtools
network = Selenium::DevTools::V91::Network.new(devtools)
network.enable
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

When debugging I see something strange: on creating the DevTools object there seems to be an exception at the `socket` method:

[image]

Unfortunately I can't figure out why this happens and didn't find anything about this. I tried to force into the `.new` method which fails somewhere but it doesn't take me anywhere.

Have you stumbled upon something similar or does anyone have some advice on how to properly use the DevTools in Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Selenium 4 DevTools, but there is another way you can incorporate this.

To access DevTools, you need to first mention them in your YML file in Ruby. Something like this

```
chrome:
  switches:
    - auto-open-devtools-for-tabs
  prefs:
    download:
        default_directory: downloads/
    devtools:
        preferences:
            panel-selectedTab: '"network"'
```

Similarly, if you want to open Console tab you can change from network to console tab.

Also if you want to record the content you can try this particular gem in Ruby which helps to screen record test cases in Ruby [Screenrecord](https://github.com/kapoorlakshya/ffmpeg-screenrecorder)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be NO ruby documentation around using the devtools, but this works for me:

```
# Install the selenium-webdriver and selenium-devtools gems

require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
devtools = driver.devtools

network = devtools.send(:network)
network.enable

network.on(:request_will_be_sent) do |params|
  # Code to inspect requests that will be sent
end

network.on(:response_received) do |params|
  # Code to inspect responses
end
```

**More info**

Instead of instantiating a network object, you can use these symbols to instantiate a number of devtool objects depending on your version of the chrome devtools protocol (CDP)): https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/DevTools/V121.html

```
console = devtools.send(:console)
console.enable

console.on(:message_added) do |params|
  # Code to inspect console messages
end
```

```
animations = devtools.send(:animation)
animations.enable

animations.on(:animation_started) do |params|
  # Code to run when animations start
end
```

....etc

The only documentation I found on the specific types of events that can be registered was inside the actual selenium-devtools gem when I inspected the code locally - I could not find any rubydocs nor the source code on github (If you find that, please comment the links)